# Uniform continuity of length function on geodesic currents

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, teichmuller-theory

I'm starting to study geodesic currents and I have a question concerning uniform continuity.

Let's take $S$ a closed surface of genus $g$ and $GC(S)$ the space of geodesic currents on $S$ (as it is defined by Bonahon, endowed with the weak star topology). Let's call $\mathcal{C}(S)$ the set of isotopy classes of closed curves on $S$ and $\mathcal{S}\subset\mathcal{C}(S)$ the subset corresponding to simple closed curves.

It is known that $\mathcal{C}(S)$ injects in $GC(S)$ and that there is a continuous extension $i:GC(S)\times GC(S)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ of the intersection number on $\mathcal{C}(S)$ .

Writing $T(S)$ for the Teichmuller space of $S$, it is also known that there is an injection $T(S)\rightarrow GC(S)$ which sends a hyperbolic metric $h$ to the Liouville current $L_h$.
For every Liouville current $L_h$ and every $\alpha\in \mathcal{S}$ it is true $l_h(\alpha)=i(L_h,\alpha)$.

My question is: I know that, for every $h\in T(S)$ hyperbolic metric, that the function $i(L_h,-):\mathcal{S}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ is continuous, but is it also *uniformly* continuous?

Comment: For uniform continuity you have to specify a metric on $C(S)$ (or, at least, a uniformity), what is it? Maybe I am misremembering, but I think Bonahon only defines a topology on $C(S)$ and the space does not have a natural metric.

Comment: The currents space $C(S)$ has a natural metrizable uniform structure, defined by Bonahon at the bottom of page 141 of his paper.